# Confusion about definition of Bond Enthalpy

Tags: bond

My Chemistry textbook defines bond enthalpy as "*amount of energy required to break one mole of bonds of a particular type between two atoms in gaseous state*".
Can someone confirm to me whether

> a particular type

is related to bond order, to the atoms involved, both, or something else?

Also, should not the bond enthalpy of all diatomic molecules be large as **one mole** of bonds to be broken. But this does not happens. Why?

Comment: Well, it **is** pretty large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bond energies are usually given for each bond-type. You can see [this table of values](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Chemical_Bonding/Fundamentals_of_Chemical_Bonding/Bond_Energies), for example (that's a great site). In order to clasify them we could say that particular type means clasify the bond according to the atoms and to bond-order. So you have C=O, C-O, N=C, N-C, and so on.

If you check the site, look that those values are positive, meaning that the energy -as you said- is the necessary to break the bond. If you need to estimate the difference in enthalpy of formation of:

$$\ce{A<=>B}$$

you will need to change sign of bond-enthalpy values (because usually entalphy is of *formation*).

The energy is calculated per mol, as you say. And it is a very big value, bigger than enthalpy of vibration, rotation or translation.

Comment: So by different _type_ we mean different kind of atoms and bond orders and not single,double,triple bonds etc?Thanks